# How to keep SSH tunnel alive

Tags: shell, ssh-tunnel

Good day, I have the shell script which does a lot of things including opening SSH tunnels to the specific servers and services. No problem with setting tunnel up, test it and shut tunnel down. But I have an issue with keeping tunnels alive. Unfortunately I can't change configuration on the server, so I need to implement some kind of "keep alive mechanism" on my side. Here is the function which opens the tunnel:

```
ssh_tunnel_up () {
  if lsof -Pi :${local_port} -sTCP:LISTEN -t > /dev/null ; then
  echo "Port is in use, please check with netstat -anlp | grep   ${local_port}. Exiting..."
else
/usr/bin/ssh -24 -fN ${username}@${node_dev} -L ${server_local_port}:${server_dev}:${server_remote_port}
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Tunnel to Server UI created successfully"
   else
    echo "An error occurred creating a tunnel  RC was $?"
   fi
 fi
```

}

Here is the function which terminates the tunnel:

```
ssh_tunnel_down () {
   if lsof -Pi :${local_port} -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
     while lsof -t -i:${local_port} > /dev/null ; do
       echo "Port is in use. Closing the port"
       kill -9 $( lsof -t -i:${local_port} )
       sleep 1
     done
   else
     echo "Port is already free. Nothing to do. Exiting..."
   fi
}
```

My question is, how to keep the tunnel alive and how to terminate the "keep alive mechanism" when you terminate the tunnel. I guess I have to use **while do done** loop, but I can't figure out how to implement this.

Thank you very much,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (HOMEDIR)/.ssh/config, add this:

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Comment: Glad to help, Happy new year to you